# IntelliJ Still demands Jack for Java 8

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am completely new in Android. 
I am using **build:gradle:2.3.3**. And setup IntelliJ 2017.2 Eap mannualy for using **Gradle 4.0**
But I has an error:

```
   Error:Jack is required to support java 8 language features. Either enable Jack or remove sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.
```

My gradle, 
top-level:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:gradle-groovy-android-plugin:0.3.10'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

//apply plugin: 'android-aspectj'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.headfirst.irina.stopwatch"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Intellij gradle settings:
[image: Intellij gradle setup with gradle 4.0 setuped manually]

I need AspectJ support for Android, so I cant use jack.

How to fix this error withou jack?

Comment: `Either enable Jack or remove sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8` you are not listening to android studio, just remove `compileOptions`   DSL

Comment: Try with changing from Java 8 to Java 7.

Comment: I am a stupid idiot. There are need 3.0.0-alpha1 version.http://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html.   I've just copied version from http://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-plugin

Comment: No, the latest version in maven repositor is 2.3.3. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle As far as in android studio: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#revisions